# When to use ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction and when ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I just stumbled upon the fact that there are two classes that apparently do very similar things and it is not clear to me from the documentation when to use which.

[ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/reactive/function/client/ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction.html) and
[ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/reactive/function/client/ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction.html)

both live in the same package of Spring-Boot-Security-oauth2-resource-server and serve the same purpose of transporting a bearer token from the Context into outgoing http requests.

From the names I would have guessed that the Serv**let** option would be used for non Reactor projects while the Serv**er** version would be used with project Reactor. <s>However that doesn't seem to be the case. At least the Serv**let** version seems to be working with Spring-WebFlux.</s>

Can anyone please explain when to use which implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We apparently had a false observation when using the *ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction*. I corrected this in the original Question.

It turns out the *ServletBearerExchangeFilterFunction* can be used to configure a WebClient for use in a WebMVC (Thread based request processing) context while the *ServerBearerExchangeFilterFunction* works when using SpringWebFlux.

Comment: This is true for all naming of similar classes in Spring too, you'll notice a lot of Servlet vs. Server defined classes along with some Reactive<Classes> too